# angular js module cannot be loaded

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting with AngularJS. Just tried hands with a simple snippet (below). But I am seeing the error in the browser console.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module notesApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'notesApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
<html ng-app="notesApp">
    <body ng-controller="notesMainCtrl as ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="ctrl.submitAction()">
            <input type="text"></input>
            <input type="password"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
        <span>username:{{ctrl.username}}  password:{{ctrl.password}}</span>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('notesApp',[])
                    .controller('notesMainCtrl',[function(){
                        this.username="username";
                        this.password="password";
                        this.submitAction=function(){
                            console.log(this.username+':::'this.password);
                        };
                    }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this maybe causing your issue: `console.log(this.username+':::'this.password);` there is no `+` between the string and `this.password`

Comment: Hi, welcome to angular for more practice i suggestion do this project for more information [Angular phonecat project](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of things, here is [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIA3PNH50Tfe3aix3FAk?p=preview) plunker..

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js" />`

this can't be self closing. i.e. needs `</script>`

`console.log(this.username+':::'this.password);`

there is a missing `+` sign here between `':::'` and `this.password`

--- Edit ---

Just some other observations, you are missing `ng-model` on the input boxes, so they won't `two-way` data bind any information back to the controller.

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" />
```

Comment: Thank you Callum!! It worked.
I was able to see the angular source files from browser developer tools > Source > ajax.googleapis.com > ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19. So I was under impression that angularjs rightly loaded.